# selecting 2D sub-slice of a 2D-slice using ranges in go

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I'm getting a surprising result when selecting a 2D sub-slice of a slice.
Consider the following 2D int array

```
a := [][]int{
    {0, 1, 2, 3},
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {2, 3, 4, 5},
    {3, 4, 5, 6},
}
```

To select the top left 3x3 2D slice using ranges I would use

```
b := a[0:2][0:2]
```

I would expect the result to be

```
[[0 1 2] [1 2 3] [2 3 4]]
```

however the second index range doesn't seem to have any effect, and returns the following instead:

```
[[0 1 2 3] [1 2 3 4] [2 3 4 5]]
```

What am I missing? Can you simply not select a sub-slice like this where the dimension > 1 ?

Comment: You can't do "easily" what you want. Slices and arrays are not 2-dimensional, they  are just composed to form a multi-dimensional object. See [How is two dimensional array's memory representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561140/how-is-two-dimensional-arrays-memory-representation/39561477#39561477).

Comment: What you're talking about is just not something that Go does. `a[0:2]`is a slice consisting of the first three elements of `a` (i.e., a slice of 3 `[]int`s). If you do the same slice operation on that, you just get the same thing, as you saw. You may want to take a look at these explanations of how slices work:
https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7
https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: @AndySchweig thanks that's just the explanation I needed. I guess I was naively hoping for a `numpy` type capability

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do  what you want in a single step. Slices and arrays are not 2-dimensional, they are just composed to form a multi-dimensional object. See [How is two dimensional array's memory representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561140/how-is-two-dimensional-arrays-memory-representation/39561477#39561477)

So with a slice expression, you just get a slice that will hold a subset of the "full" rows, and its type will be the same: `[][]int`. If you slice it again, you just slicing the slice of rows again.

Also note that the higher index in a slice expression is exclusive, so `a[0:2]` will only have 2 rows, so you should use `a[0:3]` or simply `a[:3]` instead.

To get what you want, you have to slice the rows individually like this:

```
b := a[0:3]
for i := range b {
    b[i] = b[i][0:3]
}
fmt.Println(b)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Y1i5a8jbFiE)):

```
[[0 1 2] [1 2 3] [2 3 4]]
```

Or shorter:

```
b := a[:3]
for i, bi := range b {
    b[i] = bi[:3]
}
```