# How to create slice of nonconsecutive array indices

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I'm trying to understand slicing better.

In Fortran, for instance, if I have a 2d array, I can create a slice using `matrix(:, (/2, 5, 9/))`. This slice contains just the rows 2, 5, and 9. I'm trying to find a way to create a similar slice in Go.

I know that I can use append like this:

```
var slice [][N]
slice = append(arr[1],arr[4],arr[8])
```

and the slice has the right values, but `append` copies the values, so if I update the array, my slice does not update.

Is there a proper way to do this in Go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [Spec: Slice types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types)

> A slice is a descriptor for a **contiguous** segment of an underlying array and provides access to a numbered sequence of elements from that array.

A slice always denotes a contiguous segment of an underlying array, elements cannot be skipped between the start and end indices.

#### Using a slice of pointers

You could mimic the behavior with pointers, but then they will be pointers with all their pros and cons. For example:

```
const N = 3

s := make([][N]int, 10)
s[2] = [3]int{20, 21, 22}
s[5] = [3]int{50, 51, 52}
s[9] = [3]int{90, 91, 92}

s2 := []*[N]int{&s[2], &s[5], &s[9]}
for _, p := range s2 {
    fmt.Print(*p, " ")
}

s[2][0] = 66
fmt.Println()
for _, p := range s2 {
    fmt.Print(*p, " ")
}
```

After creating and populating `s2` (from elements of `s`), we modify elements of `s`, and print `s2` again, and we see the changed, updated value. Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/C4CoLdTmjIF)):

```
[20 21 22] [50 51 52] [90 91 92] 
[66 21 22] [50 51 52] [90 91 92]
```

### Using a slice of slices

Slices (slice headers) are similar to pointers: they are small, struct like data structures which contain a *pointer* to the first element of the slice, pointing to somewhere in an underlying array. For details, see [Are golang slices passed by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993688/are-golang-slices-passed-by-value/39993797#39993797) and [why slice values can sometimes go stale but never map values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520624/why-slice-values-can-sometimes-go-stale-but-never-map-values/55521138#55521138)

So if you would use a slice of slices instead of a slice of arrays, it would work without pointers (slice values already contain pointers).

See this example:

```
s := make([][]int, 10)
s[2] = []int{20, 21, 22}
s[5] = []int{50, 51, 52}
s[9] = []int{90, 91, 92}

s2 := [][]int{s[2], s[5], s[9]}
fmt.Println(s2)

s[2][0] = 66
fmt.Println(s2)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MlJMdcPr8fu)):

```
[[20 21 22] [50 51 52] [90 91 92]]
[[66 21 22] [50 51 52] [90 91 92]]
```

See related question: [How is two dimensional array's memory representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561140/how-is-two-dimensional-arrays-memory-representation/39561477#39561477)